# MYSQL Finding count of duplicate value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In below query there is a column called  lead_id i want to find count of duplicate lead_id 
in my result if there are  10 unique lead id i must get 10 
but it must be grouped based  on  created_time ie.. if there are 2 unique lead_id for today's date then the result would be 2 ..

```
select 
    t.created_time,
    t.timecreated,
    sum(t.suggested_pending_cnt),
    sum(t.suggested_dropped_cnt)
from
    (select 
        date_format(timecreated, '%d-%b-%Y') created_time,
            timecreated,
            case
                when source = 2 then 1
                else 0
            end suggested_pending_cnt,
            case
                when (source = 2 && directory_status = 4) then 1
                else 0
            end suggested_dropped_cnt
    from
        mg_lead_suggested_listing) t
group by t.created_time
order by t.timecreated desc
limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like u want to get the unique ids for a particular date not duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Following is the query to count duplicate records with first_name and last_name in a table.

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) as repetitions, last_name, first_name
-> FROM person_tbl
-> GROUP BY last_name, first_name
-> HAVING repetitions > 1;
```

This query will return a list of all the duplicate records in person_tbl table. In general, to identify sets of values that are duplicated, do the following:

Determine which columns contain the values that may be duplicated.

List those columns in the column selection list, along with COUNT(*).

List the columns in the GROUP BY clause as well.

Add a HAVING clause that eliminates unique values by requiring group counts to be greater than one.

Comment: can you please give me an Egg using my table
my requirement is not depending on any last_name or first_name